# Error while I want to get index of specific values from my numpy array in python

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, numpy-ndarray

I have an numpy array which I want to to find index of values from it. Here is the code:

```
for i, memb_e in enumerate(memb_e):
    if memb_e == 1:
        x1 = e[i]
        y1 = 1
print(x1)

for i, memb_e in enumerate(memb_e):
    if memb_e == 0 :
        x0 = e[i]
        y0 = 0
        if i+1 < len(memb_e) and memb_e[i+1] != 0 :
            break
```

The first loop works perfectly but I got an error for second loop which is `'numpy.float64' object is not iterable`.

Also fyi the `len(e) = len(memb_e)`.

Anyone know how to solve this problem??

Comment: notice that `print(x1)` should be indent by 2 levels

Comment: Oh maybe there is a misunderstanding. The 2nd foor loop gives me that error. The print(x1) is fine

Comment: Look at `memb_e` after the first iteration.  Is it still the array, or is it now a single number?  Or try `enumerate(memb_e)` before the start of the 2nd loop.

Comment: @hpaulj wonderful point. Since I used memb_e in first loop as a iterable variable, the memb_e changed after the first loop. Now It's working. thanks a lot.

Comment: In a list comprehension, the iteration variable does not "leak" out, but in a plain iteration like this, the last value of the variable is visible after the loop is done.  Languages vary in how they handle the scope of iteration variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a small problem which depends on the context and may raise to ambiguous behaviors: *the iteration variable is the same as the iteration object* `memb_e`.

The 1st attempt works because you don't try to access to the iteration object.

Instead, in the 2nd loop you try get the length of the list `len(memb_e)` and read a value `memb_e[i+1]` but `memb_e` is an object of the iterable, a `numpy.float64` object.

So, use a different identifier as iteration variable `for i, m_e in enumerate(memb_e)`:

```
for i, m_e in enumerate(memb_e):
    if m_e == 0:  # <- comparing the iteration variable
        x0 = e[i]
        y0 = 0
        if i+1 < len(memb_e) and memb_e[i+1] != 0: # <- iterable object
            break
```

Comment: Since I used `memb_e` as an iter var, the `memb_e` changed after the first loop. Now it's working. thanks a lot.